# Image handling in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, plupload, jquery-file-upload

I want to implement profile images to my Rails app, but I'm not quite sure what goes in to the whole proces to enable a user to upload and manage her images. What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this 2013?

I'd prefer to do as much of the heavy-lifting on the client side as possible.

What can I expect from libraries such as jQuery File Upload and Plupload, can everyting (selecting, uploading, previewing, resisizing/cropping, storing) be handled with those or do I need heavy backend solutions (Carrierwave, Paperclick etc) as well?

If some code or libraries would be given as examples of what does what and where, generally speaking I prefer task-specific libraries rather than all-in-one solutions.

I'm expecting the users to have modern browsers (FF20+, Chrome20+, IE9+, Safari5+).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries.  For a start look at the following at railscasts

[Rails Image Libraries](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=image)

Comment: Yes, but what is the big scheme of the process to handle images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use paperclip or carrierwave for backend image handling. And if you want to use front end manipulation like cropping, resizing etc. you can use jquery.

If you are looking for some sample code, you can also take referance from this open source application:

https://github.com/aman199002/Album-App